# Infinitest with Eclipse 4 (Juno)

Tags: java, eclipse, infinitest

All,

I've been trying to configure Infinitest (http://infinitest.github.com/) with Eclipse 4.2 (Juno). It seems to install correctly, however I can not get the status bar to show up and display information about the tests I've run. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install it via update site? Try to modify a class which you know will result in a test-failure. Check inifinitest properties and enable it. In my eclipse I see inifinte status in "status bar" (do not know wheter this is correct name) maybe some other plugin hides it.